# Cannot find fetchall while calling oracle stored procedures from Django

Tags: python, django, oracle

I am new to Oracle databases. I need to call a Oracle Stored Procedure from my Django project. That procedure returns a cursor. Below is the procedure

```
create or replace procedure test_proc (val in NVARCHAR2, c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
begin
    open c1 for
    select * from rfc_types_matcher;
end;
```

This is how I am making call to procedure from my Django application

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', '10710', service_name='sname')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'user', password='pass', dsn=dsn_tns)
cursor = conn.cursor()

out_val = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
params.append(out_val)
data1 = cursor.callproc(sp_name, params)
data = out_val.getvalue()
```

But if I do cursor.fetchall() it says its not a query.

But if I run cursor.execute("raw query") I can get cursor.fetchall()

How to get resultset of a stored procedure?

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#ref-cursor-bind-variables). Here's an example of how to use ref_cursor

Comment: Also see the cx_Oracle example [ref_cursor.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/ref_cursor.py).